# Is there a term in psychology that describes being involved in something to a point of finding beauty in it?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, personality, terminology

More appropriately I am Looking for a word that describes fetishizing(placing too much importance in) something that you are involved with to a point of finding beauty in it i.e. the illusion of beauty in what you do to a point of assuming that the people who don't see it don't appreciate beauty at all.

I found this term called "Focusing Illusion", but "Focusing illusion" signifies over-emphasis or placing too much importance on one aspect of an event to an extent where you mistake or incorrectly/partially assume factors contributing to causality. So that doesn't fit my need.

Example 1: An English literature admirer who has read and reviewed everything by let's say Shakespeare to a point of finding beauty in it and thinks anyone who does not find beauty in Shakespeare does not appreciate beauty at all or has a false idea of beauty.

Example 2: A mathematician let us say an algebraic geometry expert finds beauty in the mathematics of Grothendieck construction and keeps raving about it to others but when they fail to find it, s/he generalizes that person to be incapable of appreciating beauty at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. [Not all psychological phenomena needs a specific term in psychology other than the general term already applied](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2374). Do you think there should there be a specific term other than, say, "high appreciation"? If so, can you please provide some insight into what makes you think that?

Comment: Thank you, I understand. My question was motivated by the term I mentioned above "Focusing Illusion", on which I am writing an essay. But wanted something that I could compare/contrast with it, which still had a negative connotation to it, as in someone so much involved in something to a point of not being able to understand that not finding beauty in what they think is beautiful doesn't necessarily mean philistinism or dullness.

Comment: Related: [What is the name of the cognitive bias where an expert overestimates the knowledge of others?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/3801/7001)